# Rails: Pass params to before_filter authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Below is my controller class:

```
class PController < ApplicationController

  before_filter authenticate_user! 

  def show
    logger.info("I am now logged in")
    if params.has_key?(:p) and params.has_key?(:t)
      # Do something
    end

  end
end
```

I want to pass the GET parameters to authenticate_user for processing. On successful login get back to the same controller along with the parameters. Please help me to learn the way to achieve this.

Comment: Which type of parameters are you passing? GET params are stored in the URL, so in theory storing the URL should give you the params. However it might get messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise already does that for you but if you want to do it yourself, may be create a different method to authenticate the user like following:

```
class PController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :restrict_access 

  def show
    logger.info("I am now logged in")
    if params.has_key?(:p) and params.has_key?(:t)
      # Do something
    end

  end
end



def restrict_access
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Log the user in and redirect to the show page.
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'login'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we will store the request url to session, after logging in successfully, we will go back to that url. To achieve this, I define some functions in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  after_filter :store_location

  # For devise    
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    previous_url
  end    

  private

  def previous_url
    url = session[:previous_url]
    url.present? ? url : '/'
  end

  def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited
    # we will store only get request which doesn't have /user/ pattern and not a ajax request
    should_store_url = request.get? && !request.path.include?('/users/') && !request.xhr?
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath if should_store_url
  end
end
```

If we are using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) will automatically call `after_sign_in_path_for` for us, otherwise, we will manually call this in order to go back to the request before logging in.

For more detail, we can go [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/280d12b81cbb15796188a6b6c00dc9658a3f6961/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) to understand why we need to overwrite `after_sign_in_path_for` to make it work (Yup for [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) guys)